# Object variable only showing the last value

Tags: c#, arrays, ssis, etl, subdirectory

The code below returns only the most recent value in the loop. What do I need to do for it to show all the values that are being iterated over? The reason I am using this method instead of `SearchOption.AllDirectory` is because there is a folder path I am not able to access. I did try using `UnauthorizedAccessException` with a `try` and `catch`, but that returns an empty value because it keeps on terminating the loop.

```
public void Main()
{
    string path = @"drive"; // TODO  
    ApplyAllFiles(path, ProcessFile);
}    

public void ProcessFile(string path) 
{
    /* ... */
}

public void ApplyAllFiles(string folder, Action<string> fileAction)
{
    System.Collections.ArrayList FileList = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
    List<string> logger = new List<string>();

    DateTime DateFilter = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6);

    foreach (string file in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
    {
        fileAction(file);
    }
    foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
    {
        string rootfolder = "root folder";

        if (subDir.Contains(rootfolder))
        {   
            FileList.Add(subDir);
            Dts.Variables["User::objDirectoryList"].Value = FileList;
           //MessageBox.Show(subDir);
        }
        try
        {
            ApplyAllFiles(subDir, fileAction);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            logger.Add(e.Message);

        }
        catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
        {
            logger.Add(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What object are you talking about? Possibly `FileList`? What does "return" mean to you? What "values" are you "showing", and where?

Comment: are you talking about `Dts.Variables["User::objDirectoryList"].Value = FileList;`? if thats the case you might want to move it outside the for loop

Comment: @EdPlunkett I am trying to assign FileList array to the object variable User::objDirectoryList and it should return a list of folder paths. However, right now it only returns the last folder path in the list.

Comment: @Nilesh yes, i have and it doesnt rutrun anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the `FileList` declaration outside the function, also remove `Dts.Variables["User::objDirectoryList"].Value = FileList;` outside the loop:

```
System.Collections.ArrayList FileList = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

public void Main()
{
    string path = @"drive"; // TODO  
    ApplyAllFiles(path, ProcessFile);
    Dts.Variables["User::objDirectoryList"].Value = FileList;
}    

public void ProcessFile(string path) 
{
    /* ... */
}

public void ApplyAllFiles(string folder, Action<string> fileAction)
{

    List<string> logger = new List<string>();

    DateTime DateFilter = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6);

    foreach (string file in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
    {
        fileAction(file);
    }
    foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
    {
        string rootfolder = "root folder";

        if (subDir.Contains(rootfolder))
        {   
            FileList.Add(subDir);
            //MessageBox.Show(subDir);
        }
        try
        {
            ApplyAllFiles(subDir, fileAction);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            logger.Add(e.Message);

        }
        catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
        {
            logger.Add(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```